# Monitoring IPSEC traffic on Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, snmp, cacti

I have cacti monitoring a bunch of things on my Cisco ASA 5505s, but nothing to indicate the level of traffic flowing through VPN tunnels on them.

Is this data available through SNMP on the ASA, and has anyone here managed to graph this in Cacti or another system?

NB - I am most interested in monitoring the traffic from my remote sites, rather than the total IPSEC traffic coming into HQ's ASA 5510.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASA does indeed support SNMP monitoring of IPSEC tunnels. It doesn't look like cacti has the required templates installed by default. These links may be helpful:

[Cacti • View topic - Cisco ASA/PIX VPN Statistics](http://forums.cacti.net/about27211.html)
[Cacti • View topic - Cisco ASA templates - YMMV](http://forums.cacti.net/about10589.html)
http://docs.cacti.net/usertemplate:host:cisco:asa_55xx

To a lesser extent, maybe this post: [Cacti • View topic - [HOWTO] Add new MIB Variables to Cacti](http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=4143)

Comment: Thanks for those.  I am already using the asa_55xx templates in the last two links, but hadn't seen the top one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out VPNTTG (VPN Tunnel Traffic Grapher) is a software for monitoring Cisco ASA IPSec Tunnel traffic.

Advantage of VPNTTG over other SNMP based monitoring software's is following: Other (commonly used) software's are working with static OID numbers, i.e. whenever tunnel disconnects and reconnects, it gets assigned a new OID number. This means that the historical data, gathered on the connection, is lost each time. However, VPNTTG works with VPN peer's IP address and it stores for each VPN tunnel historical monitoring data into the Database.

For more information about VPNTTG please visit www.vpnttg.com